# Image Overlay Using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, overlay

I am currently using bootstrap and have a 3x3 grid of images. They are 200x200 images and I have looked EVERYWHERE to try and find a way to get an overlay to work on them. I only recently started writing code.

Serenbe.com has exactly what I am looking for about halfway down the page (also a 3x3 grid).  The photo brightens, and a logo appears over it when you run your cursor over it. However, I would settle for text/links if a photo is not possible or too complicated. Right now absolutely nothing is working.

My images are arranged in a div within a container. The div takes up 6 columns. And the only styling I have applied is removing the padding so that it touches the edge of the page.

Any suggestions? I am 100% lost here, anything helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: It sounds like you have written some code. Why not post it here, along with screenshots of what you get so far, and tell us what you want it to look like.

Comment: ...and  there are literally dozens (if not hundreds/thousands) of questions on how to do text on image overlays....a brief search on SO will help here..or jst look a the related links thataway ----->

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of using hover with your css? :) it's pretty cool and I think that's what the site is using for its images.

An easy way to do what you want for beginners is I would have two pictures. One being the original and the second one with the effect you want. For serenbe it seems like they just added the logo on top using photoshop, then changed the opacity of the photo.

I would then wrap your img in a div and then do something like this in your css:

```css
.customdiv{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-image:url("imagelinkhere");
}

.customdiv:hover{
  background-image:url("newimagehere");
  opacity:.5;
}
```

What this does is change the content in your div to the new picture when you hover over the div, then apply the opacity on the image.

These are just a few tips to help you get started! Good luck